# Not store data in database but return Inserted id in laravel 5.7

Tags: database, laravel

Here is my Controller. Please have a look :

```
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $ordersData = array(
            'order_date' => $date,
            'order_delivery_time' => $shipping_time,
            'order_extra_fee' => 0,
            'inserted' => $date
        );
        $ordersData['order_payment_method'] = 'cash';
        $ordersData['order_payment_status'] = 'done';
        DB::table('orders')->insert($ordersData);
        $order_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
        dd($order_id);
```

Please check it and let me know what's the issue ?

Comment: why `=` inside array ?

Comment: Still same @AkhtarMunir

Comment: can you tell me in which format does your database store date ? what's the type of `inserted` and `order_date` ?

Comment: i used Eloquent with $fillable in model, then this issue solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `$fillable` on the model yet?

```
protected $fillable = ['order_date', 'order_delivery_time', 'order_extra_fee', 'inserted', 'order_payment_method', 'order_payment_status'];
```

Comment: later i used Eloquent with $fillable in model, then this issue solved. Thanks